Label anchoring and placement settings (geometry generator label placement by plugin)
I'm trying to set up a plugin applying custom labels for lines created by Geometry Generator. I want the labels to be "on line", something that's easily set manually:

Based on documentation I should probably set OnLine attribute for QgsPalLayerSettings, but when I'm trying to do it using Python code it always end up with AboveLine checked while OnLine remain unchecked (some default?). GG code creates kind of virtual lines (not displayed) next to "main" layer feature (also generated by GG) so I'd like to have labels exactly there...
Plugin code for labels look like this:
lblSettings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
lblSettings.geometryGeneratorEnabled = True
lblSettings.geometryGeneratorType = Qgis.GeometryType.Line
lblSettings.geometryGenerator = lbString
# part above WORKS, below part doesn't (or not sure)
lblSettings.LabelPlacement = 'Line'
lblSettings.OnLine = True #same effect for OnLine=1
lblSettings.AboveLine = False
lblSettings.BelowLine = False

lab4Lyr = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(lblSettings)
vlayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
vlayer.setLabeling(lab4Lyr)

There is also a question how to handle anchoring, that doesn't work either.

I tried to set "Start of Line" and "End of Text" with strict placement behaviour, but again, code (below) doesn't change anything, despite my tries to understand documentation definition code.
lblSettings.setLineAnchorPercent = 0
lblSettings.AnchorType = 'Strict'
lblSettings.LineAnchorTextPoint = 'EndOfText'

It's probably again my lack of experience how to read/use documentation, but maybe you can help me?
There are no errors, but it doesn't do what I want.
BTW: is it intentional that Geometry Generator for labels has no Unit setting, so "location" is always in MapUnits (even if I use Milimeters in GG for layer features)?

After some digging and check I found that there has to be some other settings object used: QgsLabelLineSettings(). So, for the label settings on line layer we have something like:
# "settings objects"
lblSettings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
lblTxtFormat = QgsTextFormat()
lbLineSet = QgsLabelLineSettings()

# anchoring
lbLineSet.setAnchorType(QgsLabelLineSettings.AnchorType.Strict)
lbLineSet.setLineAnchorPercent(0)
lbLineSet.setAnchorTextPoint(QgsLabelLineSettings.AnchorTextPoint.EndOfText)
lbLineSet.setAnchorClipping(QgsLabelLineSettings.AnchorClipping.UseEntireLine)

# Geometry generated label locations based on string expression
lblSettings.geometryGeneratorEnabled = True
lblSettings.geometryGeneratorType = Qgis.GeometryType.Line
lblSettings.geometryGenerator = lbString
lblSettings.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.Line #parallel

# text 
lblTxtFormat.setFont(QFont("Arial Narrow", 8))
lblTxtFormat.setSize(8)

# combine settings
lblSettings.setLineSettings(lbLineSet)
lblSettings.setFormat(lblTxtFormat)
lblSettings.placementFlags = 9 #OnLine=1 + MapOrientation=8
labelsWhole = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(lblSettings)

# apply to layer
vlayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
vlayer.setLabeling(labelsWhole)
vlayer.triggerRepaint()

I'm still don't know few other things like: how to apply expression instead of simple field name as label (lblSettings.fieldName = QgsExpression(str) isn't working) or how to format label numbers (round to integers - manually its easy in menu).
But I really hope "solutions" above will be useful to others.
I'll also change slightly question text for easier search.

It's not final answer, will be updated when I find (full) solution, but:
General Setting to "Parallel" is set with:
lblSettings.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.Line #parallel

This can be changed to other values like Qgis.LabelPlacement.Curved, but can't be set to value like: lblSettings.placement = 2 despite you can display value using lblSettings.placement (result is <LabelPlacement.Line: 2>).
On the other hand we have OnLine setting that can be set with:
lblSettings.placementFlags = 1 #OnLine=1

This can be combined with other options like:
lblSettings.placementFlags = 9 #OnLine=1 + MapOrientation=8

I might have not enough experience with QGIS objects etc., but... this seems to me not very consistent and not well documented. It there were some examples it might be easier, for now: there is definitely room for improvements.
